# Prevent inline suggestions in email as sender

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook, outlook-web-access

Outlook is able to make suggestions for meetings based on what is written in the text. Because this has caused problems in the past (and I don't want this feature in general), I wish to disable it *as sender*. This means that I do not want any client of any recipient to automatically present a suggestion for a meeting. To narrow it down, it would be nice to at least prevent OWA/outlook from making suggestions.

Example text: 
`Our next meeting will be held on Friday September 18th from 13:15 to 14:00 at Someroom or via Zoom`

Results in the following (note the "When: We think this event time has passed"):
[image: Figure meeting suggestion window]

Things I've tried:

I tested which part of the sentence actually causes the suggestion, but results are mixed:

**Messing up the date/time**
`Our next meeting will be held on FridaySeptember18thfrom13:15to14:00atSomeroom or via Zoom` In some cases generates a suggestion and in some cases doesn't (I literally pasted this exact text in one e-mail and it did not generate a suggestion, then in the second exactly-the-same e-mail it did). Even the text `Our next meeting will be held on HiIamDeRuijterPleaseHelpMe` generated a suggestion:

[image]

**Messing up the start of the sentence**
Changing the sentence to `Ournextmeetingwillbeheldon Friday September 18th from 13:15 to 14:00 at Someroom or via Zoom` seems to remove the suggestion, as well as  `O u r n e x t m e e t i n g w i l l b e h e l d o n Friday September 18th from 13:15 to 14:00 at Someroom or via Zoom`. Now if I use zero width space (unicode: U+200B, HTML: ​) between all the characters in the beginning of the sentence, I get what I want, which is the normal text without a suggestion. However, my concern with this method is that some clients might render this code/html differently which I am not aware of.

**Removing specific "keywords"**
Removing "held on" still generates a suggestion. Removing "meeting" still generates a suggestion. Even removing both "meeting" and "held on" still generates a suggestion...

I would like a definite way to prevent any suggestion from my text. As mentioned, the only thing that seemed to work is using zero-width-space (non-breaking), and I'm not sure this is a safe method to use.

Answer (score 0):

Suggested Meetings is an add-in and you can try to turn it off by follow below guide.
The add-in you are looking for is the `Suggested Meetings`

Outlook Web App:
[Microsoft Support - Installed add-ins](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/installed-add-ins-a61762b7-7a82-47bd-b14e-bbc15eaeb70f#__toc335124368)

Outlook Desktop:
[Microsoft Support - View, manage, and install add-ins in Office programs](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/view-manage-and-install-add-ins-in-office-programs-16278816-1948-4028-91e5-76dca5380f8d)

Comment: Hi Akane, thanks for your answer, but this only works on the recipient side. I wish to circumvent this from the sender side.

Comment: Not quite understand what does " circumvent this from the sender side" exact mean. As akane mentioned, Outlook add-in will only affect the current users who enabled it, you could try to disable this add-in from the sender side. If I have any misunderstanding, please kindly forgive that.

Comment: Disabling the add-in only works for the local user, any received mails then do not make use of this add-in. However, I want to make sure that my e-mail does not trigger -other peoples- "Suggested Meetings" add-in. In other words, how can I write/format my e-mail text so that an enabled "Suggested Meetings" add-in does not detect a potential meeting?

Answer (score 0):

When someone sends an e-mail including a place, time, and/or date, the text will show up with a dotted underline and the text will be a different color, depending on your theme color in Office 365. Click on this link to view more details about the suggested event.
[Suggested Meetings in the Outlook Web App](http://mctc-studentservices.custhelp.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/18/%7E/suggested-meetings-in-outlook)

What if we avoid typing these keywords in one sentence at the same time?
Or type like below?

Our next meeting will be held on (+ "enter")

**HiIamDeRuijterPleaseHelpMe**